# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not configure overrides from file: hibernate.reveng.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle10g, hibernate-mapping

[Hibernate code 3.6] connected with oracle database
I have already my database with schema DB1, recently I added a new tables (5 tables) in my dababase

so I'm using hibernate with eclipse to generate .class and hbm.xml for mapping with database

and I need just to convert the 5 five new tables that are independent I mean no mapping one to one or one to many

on the other side there is a mapping between this 5 tables

this is my config:

[image]

and this is my config file hibernate.reveng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <table-filter match-schema="XX" match-name="tab1"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="XX" match-name="tab2"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="XX" match-name="tab3"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="XX" match-name="tab4"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="XX" match-name="tab5"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

when I generate this **Hibernate code configuration** without hibernate.reveng.xml
(thats mean he will generate all tables from database) it working well I have all my tab1,2,3,4,5 well created but with all other tables

so me I need generate just my new tables

please could you help me

Answer (score 1):

I solved my exception after changing the DOCTYPE

I change this

```
<!-- dont know why but its not working -->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >
```

by this one

```
<!-- works fine -->

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Today after upgrades, I fix the problem changing my DOCTYPE.

I removed this (doesn't work)

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >
```

with this(Works)

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >
```